# Cannot install miniconda on Mint Linux

Tags: python, linux-mint, miniconda

I downloaded miniconda `Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh` on the web site this morning (Nov. 18).
I was able to install it on CentOS 8, but not Mint Linux 19.1.

Error message:

```
$ ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh 

Welcome to Miniconda3 4.7.12

In order to continue the installation process, please review the license agreement. Please, press ENTER to continue
>>> 
        LICENSE TEXT REMOVED <----------------------

Do you accept the license terms? [yes|no] [no] >>> yes

Miniconda3 will now be installed into this location: /home/USER/miniconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/USER/miniconda3] >>> /home/USER/miniconda3-linux PREFIX=/home/USER/miniconda3-linux 
Unpacking payload ... 
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:                           
''' Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 367, in _queue_management_worker 
    File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv TypeError:
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg' '''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "entry_point.py", line 76, in <module>   
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 483, in
_chain_from_iterable_of_lists   
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator   
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 435, in result   
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in
__get_result concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly 
  while the future was running or pending. [3596] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

What I tried:

- since the default python link (/usr/bin/python) pointed to 2.7, I replaced the link to point to 3.6.  No help there.
- Mint $(uname -a):Linux mb-mint19 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Mint version: 19.1 (Tessa)
- CentOS $(uname -a): Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.0-80.11.2.el8_0.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 24 11:32:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- CentOS version: 8 (Core)
- I looked at the code but did not find the error in these Python files (I am not a guru with Python).

Comment: My bad, I misread your question: I thought you were having trouble *installing linux mint*. I've edited your question title to better reflect the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: No.  What I did is copy it from CentOS to Mint (the whole directory, after install).